# How can I realise a script on Selenium python:push on popup button and go to the page?

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

How can I realise a script on Selenium python:push on a popup button and go to the page?

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.strava.com/login')
email = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
password = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
login = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-button"]')
email.send_keys('email')
password.send_keys('password')
login.click()

## Here comes the troubles
time.sleep(3)
hover = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container-nav"]/ul[1]/li[3]/a')
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(hover).perform()
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container-nav"]/ul[1]/li[3]/ul/li[4]/a').click()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "realise"? Can you elaborate? It is OK to do it here in comments.

Comment: how to do this)))

Comment: Try something like this.  

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.linkText("MainMenu"));
action.moveToElement(mainMenu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("submenuxpath"))).click().build().perform();